# Помощь в поиске плагина для webpack3

Tags: javascript, svg, плагин, webpack2

Нужна помощь в поиске плагина для `webpack 3` который будет "пробегать" по указанной в опциях директории, содержащий `svg`-файлы и компилить файл формата `scss` со следующим содержанием:

```
.n-icon  {
  &-24-hours {
      &:before {
          content: '';
          width: em(26);
          height: em(26);
          background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%2226%22%20height%3D%2226%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2026%2026%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cg%20stroke%3D%22%23A1A1A2%22%20stroke-width%3D%222%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20fill-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%20stroke-linecap%3D%22round%22%20stroke-linejoin%3D%22round%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M25%2013c0%206.627-5.373%2012-12%2012S1%2019.627%201%2013%206.373%201%2013%201c4.836%200%209.004%202.86%2010.904%206.983%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M24.465%204.303l-.51%203.807-3.557-.477%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M17.8%2017V9l-4%205.6h6.4%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M11.4%2017H6.6s4.8-3.7%204.8-5.6C11.4%2010.07%2010.205%209%209%209c-1.205%200-2.4%201.195-2.4%202.4%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
          background-size: cover;
      }
  }
  &-access {
      &:before {
          content: '';
          width: em(48);
          height: em(48);
          background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%2248%22%20height%3D%2248%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2048%2048%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cg%20stroke%3D%22none%22%20stroke-width%3D%221%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20fill-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%3E%3Crect%20fill%3D%22%23468CE4%22%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20width%3D%2248%22%20height%3D%2248%22%20rx%3D%2224%22%2F%3E%3Cg%20stroke%3D%22%23FFF%22%20stroke-linecap%3D%22round%22%20stroke-linejoin%3D%22round%22%20stroke-width%3D%222%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M16.364%2013l3.818%208.847c0%202.094-1.928%203.792-5.09%203.792-3.164%200-5.092-1.7-5.092-3.793L16.364%2013h15.272L38%2021.847c0%202.094-1.928%203.792-5.09%203.792-3.164%200-5.092-1.7-5.092-3.793L31.636%2013%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M24%2013v21.486%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M10%2021.847h10.182%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M27.818%2021.847H38%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
          background-size: cover;
      }
  }
...
```

Пока удалось найти более менее подходящий плагин `SVG Spritemap Webpack Plugin`, однако, он не компилит ничего внятного, либо я неправильно настроил конфиг, выглядит он вот так:

```
new SVGSpritemapPlugin({
    src: path.join(source, 'icons/svg-icons/**/*.svg'),
    filename: 'icons-sprite.svg',
    // prefix: 'n-icon',
    styles: path.join(source, 'stylesheets/root/components/icons/icons.svg.scss'),
    svgo: false,
    svg4everybody: false,
}));
```

Может кто-то уже решал подобную задачу и может поделиться опытом?